# GetVirtualPath returns the first route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

Got a strange problem with my project routes.
Here are my routes:

```
            // pennames
        routes.MapRoute(
            "pennames", // Route name
            "MyHome/Authors/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Author", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        // article
        routes.MapRoute(
            "article", // Route name
            "MyHome/Articles/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

the site structure is:
Controllers
->   MyHome
-->     AuthorController
-->     ArticleController
->Views
-->   Article
--->    Index.aspx
->   Author
->      Index.aspx

But when i call

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext..
```

from the /MyHome/Article page, It always return the first routes (MyHome/Author)

Ay idean what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default it is returning first route. You should specify route name when getting virtual path. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680260.ASPX

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext, "article", ..
```